DataTables Export PDF (Arial,10)
Necesito cambiarle el Tipo de letra 'Arial' y el tamaño '10'
quise usar
doc.defaultStyle.fontSize = 10;
doc.defaultStyle.font = 'Arial';
pero no me exporta con eso, así que lo aplique como este ejemplo:

{

   extend: 'pdfHtml5',
   title: 'Portal',

   customize: function (doc) {

    doc.styles.title = {
       fontSize: '10',
       alignment: 'center',
       fontFamily: 'Arial'
    };
    doc.styles.tableBodyEven = {
        fontSize: '10',
        fontFamily: 'Arial'
    };
 
    doc.styles.tableBodyOdd = {
        fontSize: '10',
        fontFamily: 'Arial'
    };
 
    doc.styles.tableFooter = {
        fontSize: '10',
        fontFamily: 'Arial'
    };
 
 
 
}
},

Y tampoco me reconoce el Arial

Intenta con doc.defaultStyle.font = 'Arial';

al colocarle doc.defaultStyle.font = 'Arial';
me deja de exportar
